# Bar Button item and popupControl

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I am trying to display the following checkboxes when the user clicks on a

Devexpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem. This would be like a popup where the user checks the boxes and then based on the selection a report is opened.

[image]

What is the best way to go about this?
I am still learning these dev express controls. There is a PopUpControl on their documentaion
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument349

To be able to Set  BarButtonItem.DropDownControl = poppControlContainer1 the PopupControl should be on the same form as the barbuttom Item.

I dont want be putting the popUpcontainer on the same form and make another XtraForm.
How do I invoke this XtraForm with a  popup control?
I make a form with 4 checkboxes and a dialog button. But this doesnt seem very appealing to the user
Any other thoughts on the best way to show these check boxes from a bar button would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0. If you want to use you `XtraForm` as popup then you need to add `PopupControlContainer` and use `PopupControlContainer.Popup`:

```cs
private void popupControlContainer1_Popup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    popupControlContainer1.Controls.Clear();

    var form = new XtraForm1();

    form.TopLevel = false;
    form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    form.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;

    popupControlContainer1.Controls.Add(form);

    form.Show();
}
```

Here is result:
[image: Popup with form]

1. Without `XtraForm` you can use `PopupMenu` control with `BarEditItem` objects with `RepositoryItemCheckEdit` objects as properties for editor. You can add this controls in designer by using `Editor\CheckEdit` menu. Set the `BarEditItem.Edit.GlyphAlignment` property to `HorzAlignment.Near` and set `barButtonItem.DropDownControl = popupMenu1`.
Here is result:
[image]

Comment: For the first option, should the popupControlContainer1 be on the form containing the Barbutton item?

Comment: @user575219 It is not necessary that the `popupControlContainer1` is on the same form. You even can create it in your code without any form: `private PopupControlContainer popupControlContainer1; <...> popupControlContainer1 = new PopupControlContainer(); popupControlContainer1.Popup += popupControlContainer1_Popup; barButtonItem1.DropDownControl = popupControlContainer1; <...>`